# SwiftUI - 3 Column/Sidebar Layout with All Visible?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI's new support for multi-column sidebar layouts.  I know that I can do something like this:

```
struct SidebarContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("List 1")
            
            List {
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("List 2")
            
            Text("Hello world")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .navigationTitle("Content")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

To create my 3-column layout (2 navigation columns and then a larger content view), but initially that results in a view that looks like this:

[image]

I would have to hit the Back button in order to get the layout to look like this:

[image]

What I'd really like to have is all 3 columns be visible at the same time, without the need to hit a back button or anything, at least when an iPad is in landscape mode.  An example would look like this:

[image]

Can anyone explain how I can achieve such a layout?  I would want it to be active when my app runs on macOS or when on an iPad in landscape mode.  In portrait mode I would be fine with the navigation style shown in the first screenshot, but want all panes to be visible otherwise.  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe currently there is no way to programatically control it. The primary view wouldn’t be visible by default.

Comment: I can solve the issue **without** using NavigationView in custom way, if that feet your need let me know! but i do not know if I could finish it in 2 days! because there is multi device platform, macOs, iPad, iPhone

Comment: With SwiftUI primative View (view, list, scroll, stacks, buttons...), you can create any layout you want, don't rely on heavy default views (stack, toolbar, navigation). As my exp, they're still not stable and painful to customize.

Comment: Maybe the article of Alex Grebenyuk helps: [Triple Trouble](https://kean.blog/post/triple-trouble)

Comment: @QuangHà: Exactly, the amount of time that we should spend on them to fix the shipped bugs are much more than if we build them from zero as custom View!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Better solution

```
extension UISplitViewController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.show(.primary)        
    }
}
```

===========================

Take a look at this github project: [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

```
import Introspect

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Primary View")
                Text("Supplementary View")
                Text("Secondary View")
                    // show primary view at startup
                    .introspectSplitViewController(customize: { splitViewController in
                        splitViewController.show(.primary)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
// Implement UISplitViewControlle selector
extension View {
    public func introspectSplitViewController(customize: @escaping (UISplitViewController) -> ()) -> some View {
        return inject(UIKitIntrospectionViewController(
            selector: { introspectionViewController in
                
                // Search in ancestors
                if let splitViewController = introspectionViewController.splitViewController {
                    return splitViewController
                }
                
                // Search in siblings
                return Introspect.previousSibling(containing: UISplitViewController.self, from: introspectionViewController)
            },
            customize: customize
        ))
    }
}
```